# Setting the Alphas of a Batched Vertex Array With a Uniform Array

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d, glsl, webgl

I'm creating a 2D rendering engine with WebGL in which I'm using Texture Atlases and batching hundreds of entities at once. I need to set a unique alpha value for each entity, and I'm at a loss of how to do this.

My current fragment shader is this:

```
    precision mediump float;

    uniform float u_alpha;
    uniform sampler2D u_image;

    varying vec2 v_texCoord;

    void main () {
        vec4 texture = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(texture.rgb, texture.a * u_alpha);
    }
```

I'd like to change that global uniform into a uniform buffer or an array of unique values that will be applied to the v_texCoord, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: what about texelfetch and texture buffers?Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834058/texturing-using-texelfetch

Comment: @MichaelIV: He's using *WebGL*. There is no `texelFetch` or buffer textures in WebGL.

Comment: Hmm, then please discard my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass those values in as an attribute just like `v_texCoord`.

in vertex shader

```
attribute float a_alpha;
varying float v_alpha;
...
void main() {
   ...
   v_alpha = a_alpha;  // pass the alpha values to the fragment shader.
   ...
}
```

in fragment shader

```
varying float v_alpha;
...
gl_FragColor = vec4(texture.rgb, texture.a * v_alpha);
```

Instead of using a separate attribute you could also just make your texture coordinates have 3 values. u, v, and alpha. In other words, change `v_texCoord` to a `vec3`. Update the attribute in the vertex shader to take a `vec3`. Update your UV data so each UV also has an alpha. Change your fragment shader to.

```
varying vec3 v_texCoord;

void main () {
    vec4 texture = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord.xy);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(texture.rgb, texture.a * v_texCoord.z);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I took your second suggestion, as it's far more eloquent. Nearly missed having to set the proper # of components in my vertexAttribPointer after binding my buffer, but I got it.